# Docker Hub - pull fake image

Tags: docker, cosign-api

I trying to play a bit with the [Sigstore's](https://www.sigstore.dev) cosign tool.
The tool is signing the image and then uploading the signature to the same repository.

So if I have a tag - `tool:latest` and I sign it, the tool creates a new tag named - `<digest_of_latest>.sig`

I want to somehow download that tag's data, but if I try to `docker pull` - I get an error that docker cannot load the image (which is right, this is not real image).

is there a way to download the raw data file from the docker hub repository ?

Comment: Are you able to use [this script](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh) to download the raw manifest file?

Comment: unfortunately no, it works with latest, but when I try to change the tag name to - sha256-f54a58bc1aac5ea1a25d796ae155dc228b3f0e11d046ae276b39c4bf2f13d8c4.sig it's getting 404

Comment: @MeirTolpin did you happen to find a solution for this?